# Understanding Device Contexts

Tags: mfc, gdi

As a relative newcomer to MFC, I see Device Contexts (DCs) a lot. I vaguely understand that it's something to do with drawing, but the specifics are not very well explained anywhere that I can find. What does creating a "compatible Device Context" mean, and why is it important? What does SelectObject do, and how must I make a DC compatible first?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A Device Context is just a place that drawing occurs, so if you have two different DC's, you're drawing in two different places. Kind of like a file handle.

Device Contexts can refer to real-estate on screen, or to bitmaps that just reside in memory, and probably other places, too, those are just the two I can think of at the moment.

Compatible contexts are ones that have the same underlying pixel organization, by which is meant number of bits per pixel, bytes per pixel, color organization and so forth. Memory bitmap device contexts can have any organization you want, but your screen contexts are going to be related (eventually) to buffers on your graphics card, which will (depending on mode, etc) have a very specific pixel organization.

Having compatible contexts means its efficient to transfer image data between them, because little or no translation of the data is required. At the other extreme, if you have a 256 color palette, 8 bit map and you try to blit it to a screen that has 8 bits each of RGBA per pixel, every last pixel will require significant massaging as it is copied and so copying incompatible bitmaps is very much slower. According to the Win32 SDK documentation, at least BitBlt() and StretchBlt() "convert the source color format to match the destination format", so it can be done.

Investigate CreateCompatibleDC() and CreateCompatibleBitmap() as starting points for how to create drawing contexts that are compatible with already existing ones.

SelectObject() controls which resources are currently active within the device context. A context has a current pen, brush, font, and bitmap. These make a lot of the other GDI calls simpler by allowing you to specifiy fewer parameters. For instance, you don't have to specify the font when you use TextOut(), but if you want to change the font, that's where SelectObject() comes in. If you feed SelectObject() a handle to a font, the return value is a handle to the font that was in effect, and subsequent operations use the new font. Behavior is the same for the other kinds of resources, pens, brushes, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Some follow-up questions on that, then: Can you use non-compatible DCs, and still have a working program (albeit much slower)? And where does SelectObject come into the concept of Device Context Compatibility?

Comment: This is really helpful to me to understand concepts I was having trouble to understand. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

<sub><sub>(Old question but this is shown when googling...)</sub></sub>

I'm afraid that, for beginners, the selected answer can be a bit misleading.
Please keep in mind that MFC wraps the Win32 API, so we need to see from the Win32 level, to better understand what's going on.

To understand *why* there is Device Context, we should understand **GDI**(Graphics Device Interface).

Then, why GDI exist? - For device independence. To achieve this, Microsoft made *Graphic Objects* (Brush, Pen, ...), each of which wraps and abstracts all the device dependency issues.

Now we don't have to care about different devices, and **that's the whole point of GDI**.

So we need to hold Graphic Objects(Brush, Pen, Bitmap,...) in some data structure, and that's the **Device Context**.

Then what is a *SelectObject* function?
Literally, it enables DC to "select" a Graphic Object. I.e, we use SelectObject to change a graphic object handle stored in the DC to another graphic object handle that we want to use.

Then what is a *compatible device context*? 
compatible device context(=memory device context) uses memory, rather than devices.
From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/memory-device-contexts) (emphasis mine):

> To enable applications to place output in memory rather than sending
> it to an actual device, use a special device context for bitmap
> operations called a **memory device context**. A memory DC enables the
> system to treat a portion of memory as a virtual device. It is an
> array of bits in memory that an application can use temporarily to
> store the color data for bitmaps created on a normal drawing surface.
> Because the bitmap is compatible with the device, a memory DC is also
> sometimes referred to as a **compatible device context**.
>
> The memory DC stores bitmap images for a particular device. An
> application can create a memory DC by calling the CreateCompatibleDC
> function.

Compatible DC can be used, for example, to reduce flickering because we can save the bitmap in the memory and show it once, not showing every time the image changes.

Following MSDN docs would be helpful to newbies (including me).
[Device Contexts, from the MFC viewpoint.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/device-contexts?view=msvc-170)
[Device Contexts, from the Win32 viewpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/device-contexts), and [this following section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/about-device-contexts).